# Different meanings of "footnotesep"?

Tags: geometry, latex-base

What is the difference between `footnotesep` as option of the `geometry` package and as native dimension `\footnotesep`?

It seems that

- `\usepackage[footnotesep=1em]{geometry}` sets the separation between the bottom of text body and
  the top of footnote text and
- `\setlength{\footnotesep}{1em}` sets the separation between footnotes.

But both are named `footnotestep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometry option `footnotesp` is

```
\define@key{Gm}{footnotesep}{\Gm@setlength{\skip\footins}{#1}}%
```

That is, it sets `\skip\footins`  not `\footnotesep`  which is a bit unfortunate naming, but it is what it is.